# Kitchen can't see the network configuration into Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant

I am using kitchen to test my cookbook and I made a network configuration in the Vagrantfile but the kitchen instance not see this configuration.

This is my **Vagrantfile** configuration.

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "demo-berkshelf"

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
      :mysql => {
        :server_root_password => 'rootpass',
        :server_debian_password => 'debpass',
        :server_repl_password => 'replpass'
      }
    }

    chef.run_list = [
        "recipe[demo::default]"
    ]
  end
end
```

And it is my **.kitchen.yml** configuration.

```yml
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
    driver_config:
      box: "ubuntu-12.04"

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[demo::default]
    attributes:
```

When i login into kitchen show me a network configuration that **i don't expect**

```yml
roberto@rcisla-pc:~$ kitchen login default-ubuntu-1204
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Wed Jan 22 14:02:59 2014 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@default-ubuntu-1204:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:12:96:98  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:49328 (49.3 KB)  TX bytes:42004 (42.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Where is the 33.33.33.10 that i configured in Vagrantfile?
Thanks beforehand for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Kitchen won't use your `Vagrantfile` by default; it generates its own based on the `.kitchen.yml`. See [the README](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-network) for instructions how to configure networking via it. For example:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
  - ["private_network", { ip: "192.168.33.10" }]
```

You [*can*](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-vagrantfile_erb) use a custom Vagrantfile template too, but normally it shouldn't be needed. See the [default template](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/master/templates/Vagrantfile.erb) for an example.

And finally, don't use 33.33.33.* addresses. That is a valid network owned by somebody. Use IPs from private networks like  10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16 instead. 192.168.33.* seems to be quite common with Vagrant.

Comment: For the record, 33.33.33.x is reserved by the US Department of Defense. Since most civilians are not going to be connecting to this network it's generally safe to use locally as you won't have routing collisions (although I don't recommend using it personally). I usually see this range in examples rather than used in the field.